# QTableView column width adjustable

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

Is there a way to make QTableView column widths adjustable by the user? Or is the only way to adjust the column with to make resizeColumnToContents or resizeColumnsToContents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The QTableView's [horizontal and vertical headers](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html) will allow resizing when the columns (or rows) aren't being sized according to their contents. See the [ResizeMode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#ResizeMode-enum) enum. Once resized, you'll be informed of a resize via the [SectionResized](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#sectionResized) signal.

Comment: thank you! I used a combination of setStrechLastSection(true) and setResizeMode to QHeaderView::Interactive.